# How to merge materials for joined objects?

Tags: materials, objects

I've recently starting joining similar objects in my projects, each using the same material. The issue is that each joined object retains its own material slot, even though each object uses the identical material. I figure there must be a way to merge/flatten those slots so that in the future if I want to apply a different material I don't have to apply it multiple times, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks! Blender 3.0, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: If there is only one material in there you can safely delete them all but one and all the faces that pointed to ther other material slots will be redirected to the last remaining material

Comment: Gorgious, thank you for the response. Unfortunately, when I join the objects, each object ends up with its own material name. For example, the first object has the material "metal," the second is assigned "metal.001", the third, "metal.002," and so on. If I delete any of those materials, then that joined object is not redirected to a new material.

Comment: I can't find anything what can cause this in the Preferences, but did you try to reset it?

Comment: FFeller, reset the Preferences?